# Object Binding for Thymeleaf and Spring not working

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I have `Project` object that contains the list `Roles` with `Role`object. I want to edit the project using the form. This form need to have checklist of roles. So I have binded `Project` object with `th:object`. Now when the user selects the check boxes and saves, it is failing with the error.

Form to render Check box

```
<ul class="checkbox-list">
  <li th:each="role,stat : ${allRoles}">
        <input type="checkbox" th:value="${role.id}" th:field="*{roles[__${stat.index}__].id}"/>
        <span class="primary" th:text="${role.name}"> Developer</span>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Project Object

```
public class Project {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
int id;
String name;
String description;
private String status;
private String slug;


@ManyToMany
List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();

@ManyToMany
List<Collaborator> collaborators = new ArrayList<>();
................
................
}
```

Role Object:

```
@Entity
public class Role {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
private int id;
private String name;
.............
.............
.............
}
```

Relevant Controller Methods

```
@RequestMapping("/edit-project/{slug}")
    public String editProjectFromSlug(@PathVariable String slug,Model model) {
        Project project = projectService.findProjectBySlug(slug);
        List<Role> allRoles = roleService.getAllRoles();
        //Two objects are added to the model
        model.addAttribute("project",project);
        model.addAttribute("allRoles",allRoles);
        return "edit_project";
    }

@RequestMapping(value = "/save-project", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveProject(@ModelAttribute Project project,Model model){
    projectService.saveProject(project);
    return "redirect:/projects";
}
```

[image: Error Screenshot]

I have referred multiple answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37744826/how-to-bind-an-object-list-to-checkbox-in-thymeleaf). None of them are working. The code is at this [github repo](https://github.com/tejact/SpringHibernateDuplicate). Please help me to fix this error.

Comment: can you post your controller code?

Comment: @bphilipnyc Just added controller method. Can you please try to spot the bug

Comment: Can you try adding the @PathVariable declaration?  See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20616319/the-request-sent-by-the-client-was-syntactically-incorrect-spring-mvc-jdbc-te

Comment: any solution till now?